# SQL different SELECT based on condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have SQL tables with "score" columns. Sometimes that table will have hundreds of rows and sometimes it will have less than 10 rows. I need a SQL query that outputs the top 3 scores if there are less than 10 rows, or the top 10 scores if there are more than 10 scores in the table.

I'm not sure how to do this in SQL, but something like this:

```sql
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN COUNT(*) < 10 THEN
      (
       SELECT score 
       FROM scores_table 
       ORDER BY score DESC 
       LIMIT 3
      )
    WHEN COUNT(*) > 10 THEN 
      (
       SELECT score 
       FROM scores_table 
       ORDER BY score DESC 
       LIMIT 10
      )
  END
```

The above doesn't work but hopefully it conveys what I'm trying to get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
(
 SELECT `score`
 FROM `scores_table`
 ORDER BY `score` DESC
 LIMIT 3
) 
UNION ALL
(
 SELECT `score`
 FROM `scores_table`
 WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `scores_table`) >= 10
 ORDER BY `score` DESC
 LIMIT 2, 7
)
```

Comment: This seems like what I want, but I can't get this query to work for me. What does the last line: `LIMIT 2, 7` do? (I'm very new to SQL/MySQL).

Comment: @DavidSkarbrevik . . . The "2" is the offset (starting at 0).  The "7" is the number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query !

```
SELECT `score`
 FROM `scores_table`
 WHERE COUNT(*) <= 10
 ORDER BY `score` DESC
 TOP 3

UNION 

SELECT `score`
 FROM `scores_table`
 WHERE COUNT(*) < 10
 ORDER BY `score` DESC
 TOP 10
```

Comment: I don't think MySQL has a `TOP` keyword... or at least it isn't working for me :( but otherwise seems like this would work.

Answer (score 1):

The question is interesting.

As you selected the tag "MySQL", you may not be directly interested by the answer I propose, however someone may find it useful some day.

The problem I see with the other two answers already posted is that they make use of "LIMIT" or "TOP", which are not SQL. The following query uses only standard SQL. The idea is to first fetch the third and tenth scores, then to fetch each row of the score table with a score higher than one of these.

```sql
WITH RN(score, rn) AS (
  SELECT score, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY score DESC)
  FROM score
),
BOUND(bound) AS (
  SELECT min(score)
  FROM RN
  WHERE rn IN (3, 10)
)
SELECT score.*
FROM score
INNER JOIN BOUND ON score >= bound
ORDER BY score DESC;
```

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b44b8/2/0

Comment: This works perfectly, but I'm so new to SQL that it doesn't make much sense to me how it's working. Also didn't know about SQL fiddle so thanks for that resource.